# Installing PyQt5 with Conda on Linux

Tags: pyqt5, conda

I need a new graphics backend for Matplotlib that will be capable of displaying plots over SSH, so I am trying to install PyQt5. Following [the documentation](https://anaconda.org/ipa/pyqt5) I have run

`conda install -c ipa pyqt5`

I have also tried

`conda install PyQt5`

Both led to the error

```
PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - pyqt5-5.15.3.tar.gz

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

  - file:///opt/intel/conda_channel/linux-64
  - file:///opt/intel/conda_channel/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/intel/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/intel/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

I also tried installing directly from the tar, which I downloaded, placed in the home directory, and set permissions for, but faced the error

```
conda install ~/PyQt5-5.15.3.tar.gz

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - pyqt5
```

and then the same bit with searching the following channels.

What gives? Why am I not able to install it even when I include the the necessary files?

Comment: have you tried conda search? might be string encoding issue

Comment: Thank you - after running a search, I found that `PyQt` was listed although `PyQt5` was not. `conda install PyQt` installed it successfully.